# Apply NSG/ASG by default on new subnets (Azure)

Tags: azure, triggers, network-security-groups

We manage an Azure subscription operated by several countries. Each of them is quite independant about they can do (create/edit/remove resources). A guide of good practices has been sent to them, but we (security team) would like to ensure a set of NSG is systematically applied for every new subnet/vnet created.

Giving a look to Azure Triggers, I am not sure that subnet creation belongs to the auditable events. I also was told to give a look to Azure policy, but once again I am not sure this will match our expectations which are : **For every new vnet/subnet, automatically apply a set of predefined NSG**.

Do you have any idea about a solution for our need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done work like this in the past (not this exact issue) and the way I solved it was with an Azure Function that walked the subscription and looked for these kinds of issues. You could have the code run as a Managed Identity with Reader rights on the subscription to report issues, or as a Contributor to update the setting. Here's some code that shows how you could do this with PowerShell https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/tree/master/samples/Network/enforce-nsg-on-subnet

You could consider using a Policy that has a DeployIfNotExists Action, to deploy an ARM template that contains all the data for the NSG. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/pattern-deploy-resources

You can get the ARM template by creating the NSG and getting the template:
[GettingNSGTemplate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEcSP.png)

Note also that creating a subnet is audited, you can see it in the Activity Log for the VNet. See the screen shot.

[AddingASubnet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCZ3h.png)

Comment: I had found the first link but I really like the second solution you suggest with the DeployIfNotExist Action. Thank you

Comment: @MedAl Could you please tell me how you define the template to deploy nsg with `DeployIfNotExists`?

Comment: Hi @JimXu. To be honest I didn't have the time to keep moving on that topic. And the project will probably be abandoned on our side. Good luck